# Python: Clase gestor de contexto para conexión a MySQL

Tags: python, diseño-de-clases

Estoy creando una clase de conexión a MySQL, que en realidad es un gestor de contexto, de manera que se usa conjuntamente con una expresión `with`, y me han surgido algunas dudas al respecto de cómo sería más apropiado implementarla:

```
'''
Clase (gestor de contexto con los métodos mágicos __enter__ y __exit__) para la conexión a MySQL
'''

import mysql.connector as mysql #Conector específico para MySQL

class MySQL:

    __SERVIDOR = 'localhost' #Atributos de clase privados (no se ha de acceder a ellos desde fuera de la clase) para definir la instancia de conexión
    __USUARIO = 'root'
    __CONTRASENA = ''
    __BASE_DATOS = 'recopilatorios'

    def __init__(self): #En el método iniciador se crea un diccionario con los atributos de clase

        self.instancia = {
            'host': MySQL.__SERVIDOR, #Al ser atributos de clase no se pasan como parámetros del método
            'user': MySQL.__USUARIO, #Se accede a ellos mediante el nombre de la propia clase y no con "self"
            'password': MySQL.__CONTRASENA,
            'database': MySQL.__BASE_DATOS
        }

    def __enter__(self): #Método que se invoca al comenzar la declaración "with"

        self.conexion = mysql.connect(**self.instancia) #Se crea la conexión ("**" indica que se trata de un diccionario)
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor() #Y a partir de ella, el cursor, que es el que ejecuta las consultas sobre la BD

        return self.cursor #La declaración "with" llama a esta clase, que devuelve el cursor

    def __exit__(self, tipoError, valorError, trazaError): #Método que se invoca al finalizar la declaración "with"

        if tipoError: #Si ocurre un error (valor distinto de "none") mientras se intenta realizar la operación sobre la BD

            self.conexion.rollback() #Se deshace toda la operación y se notifica el tipo y el valor del error

            print(f'Ha ocurrido un error y se ha revertido la transacción: (1) {tipoError} (2) {valorError}')

        else: self.conexion.commit() #De lo contrario, se acomete la operación

        self.cursor.close() #Cierre del cursor
        self.conexion.close() #Cierre de la conexión
```

Tal como está ahora, funciona. He definido cuatro "constantes" a modo de atributos de clase "privados" con los parámetros de conexión, que luego se le pasan a `__init__`.

Para hacer una consulta a mi base de datos, se utiliza directamente la clase y no una instancia de ésta, tal que así:

```
sql = 'SELECT titulo_cancion FROM canciones'

try:

    with MySQL() as cursor:

        cursor.execute(sql)
        resultados = cursor.fetchall()

        for resultado in resultados: print(list(resultado)[0])

except Exception as error: print(f'Ha ocurrido un error: (1) {type(error)} (2) {error}')
```

Dado que no creo instancias de `MySQL` sino que la utilizo directamente, mi duda es si no sería más apropiado el convertir todos los métodos de instancia -si bien "mágicos"- que contiene `MySQL` en métodos de clase, tal que así:

```
'''
Clase (gestor de contexto con los métodos mágicos __enter__ y __exit__) para la conexión a MySQL
'''

import mysql.connector as mysql #Conector específico para MySQL

class MySQL:

    __SERVIDOR = 'localhost' #Atributos de clase privados (no se ha de acceder a ellos desde fuera de la clase) para definir la instancia de conexión
    __USUARIO = 'root'
    __CONTRASENA = ''
    __BASE_DATOS = 'recopilatorios'

    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls): #En el método iniciador se crea un diccionario con los atributos de clase

        cls.instancia = {
            'host': MySQL.__SERVIDOR, #Al ser atributos de clase no se pasan como parámetros del método
            'user': MySQL.__USUARIO, #Se accede a ellos mediante el nombre de la propia clase (también serviría "cls") y no con "self"
            'password': MySQL.__CONTRASENA,
            'database': MySQL.__BASE_DATOS
        }

    @classmethod
    def __enter__(cls): #Método que se invoca al comenzar la declaración "with"

        cls.conexion = mysql.connect(**cls.instancia) #Se crea la conexión ("**" indica que se trata de un diccionario)
        cls.cursor = cls.conexion.cursor() #Y a partir de ella, el cursor, que es el que ejecuta las consultas sobre la BD

        return cls.cursor #La declaración "with" llama a esta clase, que devuelve el cursor

    @classmethod
    def __exit__(cls, tipoError, valorError, trazaError): #Método que se invoca al finalizar la declaración "with"

        if tipoError: #Si ocurre un error (valor distinto de "none") mientras se intenta realizar la operación sobre la BD

            cls.conexion.rollback() #Se deshace toda la operación y se notifica el tipo y el valor del error

            print(f'Ha ocurrido un error y se ha revertido la transacción: (1) {tipoError} (2) {valorError}')

        else: cls.conexion.commit() #De lo contrario, se acomete la operación

        cls.cursor.close() #Cierre del cursor
        cls.conexion.close() #Cierre de la conexión
```

También funciona, pero PyCharm me hace las siguientes advertencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se debe?

Por otro lado:

```
'user': MySQL.__USUARIO, #Se accede a ellos mediante el nombre de la propia clase (también serviría "cls") y no con "self"
```

¿Es más apropiado usar el nombre de la clase, usar `cls` o es indiferente?

Answer (score 1):

Nota: perdon la calidad de la respuesta y el codigo sin probar. En realidad, estoy en telefono. Cualquier duda o aclaracion que tengan me vendria bien que me la digan. Gracias c:

#### aclarando conceptos

En realidad, si creas una instancia. De hecho, llamar a una clase ya es instanciarla (aunque este comportamiento puede ser cambiado por metaclases).

Pero respondiendo a tu otra pregunta. Cls no es lo que crees. Primero que nada, se lo llama asi por convencion. Cambiarle el nombre al argumento no cambia el que es. Pero dejando eso de lado, cls seria la clase desde la cual es invocado el metodo, que tambien podria ser una clase derivada de MySQL. No necesariamente se trata de la clase MySQL.

Y por ultimo, sobre las advertencias, no las entiendo.

#### conclusion

Conclusion: no estas trabajando con la clase en si, estas trabajando con una instancia de dicha clase. Y por lo tanto no te conviene usar el decorador classmethod.

#### una mejor forma de crear la clase

Yo creo que la clase puede mejorarse. Podes usar atributos estaticos en la clase. Luego en `__enter__` aprovechar como python busca los atributos primero en la instancia, luego el padre, luego el padre del padre ... e intentar acceder a los atributos estaticos. Ojo, al hacer eso, si estableces en la instancia un atributo con el mismo nombre, el buscador de atributos de Python obtendra ese atributo primero y no el del padre. Si no deseas ese comportamiento, directamente obtené la clase padre de la instancia con type(self) y obten los atributos desde alli. En el ejemplo, uso el primer metodo, pero si queres podes aplicar el segundo. Cualquier complicacion dime c:

A continuacion, una parte modificada del cuerpo de la clase:

```
SERVIDOR = 'localhost' #Atributos de clase privados (no se ha de acceder a ellos desde fuera de la clase) para definir la instancia de conexión
USUARIO = 'root'
CONTRASENA = ''
BASE_DATOS = 'recopilatorios'

def __enter__(self): #Método que se invoca al comenzar la declaración "with"

    self.conexion = mysql.connect(self.SERVIDOR, self.USUARIO, self.CONTRASENA, self.BASE_DATOS, ) #Se crea la conexión ("**" indica que se trata de un diccionario)
    self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor() #Y a partir de ella, el cursor, que es el que ejecuta las consultas sobre la BD

    return self.cursor
```

#### (opinion personal) por que no usar atributos "privados"

Eso de los atributos "privados" no me convence mucho, ya que lo unico que hace en realidad es cambiar el nombre necesario para acceder al atributo fuera de la clase. Por ejemplo, se puede acceder al atributo `__hola` con `instancia.__elnombredelaclase_hola`. Es un extraño intento de crear un atributo "privado".

Comment: Por lo que he leído, al no tener Python encapsulamiento real, a los que consideres atributos protegidos se les pone un guion bajo delante, y a los privados, dos. Pero, claro, simplemente a modo "informativo".

Comment: Exactamente Javier

Comment: ¿Tú optas por no seguir esta convención? Es decir, es un proyecto personal, no va a venir ningún otro desarrollador a continuar mi código con lo cual me da igual usar encapsulamiento. Y más si ni siquiera es real.

Comment: Me parece que no es una convención, si hace algo, pero no es privado. Pero yo no lo usaria. No lo ví usado en muchos códigos. De todas formas, seguir o no las convenciones de Python es es desición propia, nadie te obliga. Pero tu código sería más entendible para otros. Por ejemplo, imagina que en lugar de "self" para referirte a la instancia de clase, usaras this o fulano... Se entendería menos el código. Al menos, esa convención la apoyo. Creo que estaría bueno que el gurú de Python de aqui te hable de ese tema.

Comment: Por cierto, no me queda claro el trozo de código que has puesto; ¿es posible combinar `cls` y `self` de esa manera?

Comment: Perdón la tardanza, no noté tu comentario.  Es un error mio, gracias por notarlo! Eso pasa por modificar código en el telefono xD Editado el fragmento.

Comment: Finalmente he creado un diccionario `INSTANCIA` con los parámetros de conexión, que paso directamente a `mysql.connect()` dentro de `__enter__`, y he eliminado `__init__`. Tendré que seguir investigando estos temas; vengo de PHP donde los únicos métodos de clase son los estáticos y me desconcierta un poco la diferenciación que se hace en Python.